# Using type constraints across typeclass instances

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-constraints

I'm trying to define a type class `Plotable` that provides a function `plotable` to return a tuple representing co-ordinates in a chart `(x,y)`, it the type of `x` and `y` does not have to be specific (ie `Double`), I think they can be any number type (they're being handed over to [Chart](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart)).

I want `plotable` to be able to deal with `Num a => Complex a` and `Num a => (a, a)`, so I wrote:

```
class Plotable a where
  plotable :: Num b => a -> (b, b)

instance Num a => Plotable (a, a) where
  plotable = id

instance Num a => Plotable (Complex a) where
  plotable c = (realPart c, imagPart c)
```

Which makes sense to me, however I'm getting the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration
    at /Users/dan.brooks/Code/haskell/coding-the-matrix/src/TheField/Plot.hs:12:10-33
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      plotable :: forall b. Num b => (a, a) -> (b, b)
    at /Users/dan.brooks/Code/haskell/coding-the-matrix/src/TheField/Plot.hs:13:3-10
  Expected type: (a, a) -> (b, b)
    Actual type: (b, b) -> (b, b)
```

But surely if `a` is constrained to `Num`, and `b` is constrained to `Num`, passing through the same value should work in this case? Is this simply a limitation of the compilier? or am I misusing typeclasses and type constraints?

Comment: Community: perhaps we should have a reference q/a for problems related to misunderstanding universal and existential quantification. These are starting to get more and more common, recently.

Comment: "But surely if a is constrained to Num, and b is constrained to Num, passing through the same value should work in this case" - surely not, or else the same argument applies to `bad :: a -> b; bad x = x`. Type variables are judgementally equal only to themselves, which is why the compiler says it can't match two distinct type variables. In a way, this is indeed a limitation of the compiler - it limits you from writing completely wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plotable :: Num b => a -> (b, b)
```

means that any of these must type check

```
plotable :: a -> (Int, Int)
plotable :: a -> (Integer, Integer)
plotable :: a -> (Double, Double)
...
```

In other words, that polymorphic type promises to the user that `plotable` can use whichever numeric type `b` the user can choose.

`id :: a -> a` does not let the user choose `b`, so it is not general enough.